# How do I bind a list of elements to a select list using ngFormModel?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Let's say I have a form component such as

```
export class FormComponent {
    form: ControlGroup;
    categories: AbstractControl;
    text: AbstractControl;
    private _categories: string[] = [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ];
    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = _formBuilder.group({
       'categories': [ this._categories ],
       'text': [ '', Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1) ]) ] 
    });
    this.categories= this.form.controls['categories'];
    this.text = this.form.controls['text'];
}
```

In my view I'd like a dropdown menu for `categories` and a text area for `text`. The text area is straightforward,

```
<form role="form" [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <div class="form-group" [class.error]="!text.valid && text.touched">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="text" rows="5" placeholder="Text goes here" 
            [ngFormControl]="text"></textarea>
        <div *ngIf="!text.valid && text.touched" class="ui error message">
            Please enter some text.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but I can't find any examples for how to create a `select` using `ngFormModel`, they all seem to use `ngModel` and an `*ngFor` loop creating the `option` tags with an `ngValue` property. Does that mean I have to mix `ngFormModel` and `ngModel` or is there a way to do this with `ngFormModel` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngFormControl` with a select this way and without using `ngModel`:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
  <div>
    <select test [ngFormControl]="form.controls.categories">
      <option *ngFor="#category of categories;#i=index" [value]="category.value">{{i}} - {{category.name}}</option>
    </select>
    categories : {{form.controls.categories.value}}
  </div>
</form>
<div (click)="updateValues()">Update values</div>
```

Here is the content of the component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class App {
  constructor(private builder:FormBuilder) {
    this.categories = [
      { name: 'Cat1', value: 'cat1' },
      { name: 'Cat2', value: 'cat2' },
      { name: 'Cat3', value: 'cat3' },
      { name: 'Cat4', value: 'cat4' }
    ];
    this.form = builder.group({
      categories: [ 'cat1' ]
    });
  }

  updateValues() {
    this.form.controls.categories.updateValue('cat3');
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/2UItcrQQWr6eowsPoE4i?p=preview.

Comment: I have a doubt: do you want to use select with multple selections?

Comment: That would be the next step, yes.

Comment: In fact, it's not supported out of the box. You need to implement a custom value accessor for this...